# jQuery autocomplete remote data using getJson with autocomplete.filter

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, getjson

Many people are using jQuery Autocomplete with a remote data source like this:

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.getJSON( "search.php", { // get the json here
      term: extractLast( request.term ) // function further, up not important
    }, response );
  }
});
```

and many people are filtering their data arrays like this:

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
  var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(myarray, request.term); //data in "myarray"

  response(results) ;
 }
});
```

I can't find any example where anyone is filtering a remote data source and I really need both. I'd like to just combine these to blocks of code if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only use the "filter" if your data is locally stored. If it is remote, you should filter it on the server side first before sending it over.

From the jQuery UI documentation:

> The Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results, instead a query string is added with a term field, which the server-side script should use for filtering the results. For example, if the source option is set to "http:// example.com" and the user types foo, a GET request would be made to http:// example.com?term=foo. The data itself can be in the same format as the local data described above.

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Your first example works well for this scenario.